# ListView inside ScrollView issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scrollview

I need to make layout just like this from picture below. Where you can see that I have user info area, review area and comments area.

The entire layout should be scrollable, because review should be very long, and that review could have a lot of comments.

Also comments area is ListView, so I thought that I should use ScrollView to scroll all layout, but it doesn't work well with ListView.

Is there any solution?

[image]

Here is the picture when I use **ListView with header and footer**.
[image]

Comment: don't use listview inside scrollview. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: you can add views as a header and footer to listview istself

Comment: If you insist : http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/12/listview-into-scrollview-in-android.html

Comment: I have tried that, but review is too large and comments area (listview) isn't visible on screen, so I can't access to it.

Comment: @Zookey - do you mean you always want to see (some of) the comments even for a very long review (as opposed to scrolling them into view at the bottom of a review?) If so, I would guess that you need two list views (say 2/3rd and 1/3rd the height of the screen) one for the reviews and one for comments, though I could see this getting messy, as you'd (a) probably have to catch scrolling a new review into view so you can display its comments; and (b) probably only show one review ata time (even if its short) because otherwise you wouldn't know which comments apply to each.

Comment: I am really close to solve this problem with ListView which use header and footer. The problem was that I used ListViw inside ScrollView, and I could not scroll down properly. Anyway, now I removed ScrollView and its a lot better, but it still have problem with scrolling. Pay attention to the slider size on this pictures: http://www.dodaj.rs/f/1g/RV/1lvtUZOt/slider.png  http://www.dodaj.rs/f/1w/C3/4UAlsLNI/slider1.png

Answer (score 0):

Do not ever use Listview inside ScrollView because Listview already contain the functionality of scrolling. Just use Fill_parent for width and height it will automatically scroll.

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

And for scrolling the whole layout you can put the review part inside header of the listview

Comment: Fill_parent to add on the ListView? But problem is that review could be very large and comments area (listview) isn't visible at screen at all.

Comment: Yes put fill_parent on listview. Thats why you have to put your review part inside header of listview ,so  when you scroll your comment part will get visible.

Comment: I will edit question and post picture with listview which use header and footer, please be here.

Comment: Question is edited, and as you can see, I can't even see comments area.

Comment: Yes, then when user scroll it he will see the comments section.Or if you want to show the comment section on the screen then you can do one thing this put your review inside a scrollview and then put this scrollview inside the header of listview.

Comment: I am really close to solve this problem with ListView which use header and footer. The problem was that I used ListView inside ScrollView, and I could not scroll down properly. Anyway, now I removed ScrollView and added header and footer to the Listview and its a lot better, but it still have problem with scrolling. Pay attention to the slider size on this pictures: dodaj.rs/f/1g/RV/1lvtUZOt/slider.png dodaj.rs/f/1w/C3/4UAlsLNI/slider1.png

Comment: I cant see the picture, sorry!

Comment: It is showing broken picture in that link you gave.

Comment: what is the problem with slider ? you can remove the slider if you want.

Comment: I think that this indicate that something is wrong, because scrolling isn't normal. Is this blue indicates that is end of list or? http://www.dodaj.rs/f/3E/Ug/3wOjJL7M/blue.png

Comment: yes that blue indicate the end of the listview and you can remove that blue thing as well by putting  android:overScrollMode="false" in your listview.

Comment: I know that, but I dont want to do that. I think that there is some problem, because I used ListView with header and footer, and this list has 15 comments, and I have problem to scroll down to that comments. I  can scroll but it is not that smooth.

Comment: Are you using ViewHolder in your listview adapter?

Comment: I would suggest you to use ViewHolder for populating the listview. Search it on google you will get lot of code it is very easy, this way your listview will be very fast as Google developers also suggest to use viewholder for making listview smooth. And one more thing in your listview xml always use fill_parent for both height and width because this is also one issue sometime of bad scrolling.

Comment: Yep, I am using fill_parent for both height and width. I will try this  with ViewHolder.

Comment: Ok...if you found that my answer/comments help you in any way , please don't forget to mark it as correct answer :)

Comment: Dont worry, I will :)